# MVC filtering actionResult from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to filter my data from dropdownlists. There are several DDL's in my page.
All of them trigers a javascript in onchange event and sends their name and value.

The ActionResult gets this data and and returns as ViewBag data to make them selected.

But I catch the datas coming from DDL's in a single filterBy parameter in ActionResult

Because of this I can't get multiple DDL's selected and cannot pass all of this values.

I can make separated parameters and catch them but I want to make my javascript and actionResult more dynamic.

How can I make this???

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use JavaScript to dynamically join the values and set a hidden input with that. Then, you would post the hidden input as your filterBy param. However, likely that's not what you *actually* want. It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve, but there's probably a better way.